# Completed writing a first author paper, not submitted

Tags: paper-submission

Hello so i completed a first author paper that has been revised with my PI. I have left for grad school without the final version submitted to a journal.

What happens now? Can the paper be submitted? Canned?  Should i expect to see it submitted?  Or should i kiss it goodbye?

Comment: Contact the PI and ask. Just because you are no longer under the PI's supervision doesn't mean you can't submit a paper with them.

Comment: Definitely don't kiss it goodbye, it's in the PI's interest to have it published and it would be a shame not to publish after you've put the work in.

Answer (score 1):

In my field (Mol Biol/Genomics) I'd say most papers are submitted after the first author has left, as grants/studentships don't generally last long enough to complete a project and get the manuscript submitted.

In theory there is nothing to stop you submitting the paper without an affiliation. In practice it will be much more convenient if the paper is submitted by your PI, who would presumably agree to pay any charges associated.

Comment: OP writes that she's "left for grad school" so presumably she has an affiliation (her grad school).